# Installing grub and xorriso on Ubuntu on Windows

Tags: ubuntu, grub, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I need to use grub-mkrescue in order to generate some ISOs. My primary working environment is on a Windows 10 machine. I use the Linux susbsystem for various tasks already.

I managed to install grub without problems, but I need xorriso in order to use grub-mkrescue. When I do `sudo apt-get install xorriso` I get the following error:

> Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   Package xorriso is not available, but is referred to by another package.
>   This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
>   is only available from another source
>
> E: Package 'xorriso' has no installation candidate

Is this supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build its statically linked version from source.

Download https://www.gnu.org/software/xorriso/xorriso-1.4.6.tar.gz
to a directory where you want to build xorriso

```
tar xzf xorriso-1.4.6.tar.gz
cd xorriso-1.4.6
touch xorriso/*.info
./configure && make
```

I assume you need packages `build-essential` and `tar`.

The command `touch xorriso/*.info` avoids the need for program `makeinfo`
from package `texinfo` which might arise in rare cases due to an unfortunate
sequence of files in `xorriso-1.4.6.tar.gz`. (For failure symptoms see
the comment by user3804799, Oct 12 at 18:56. It cannot happen on real Debian or Ubuntu, because there `tar` without option `-m` restores the timestamps from the tar archive.)

Success should yield a binary which run by

```
xorriso/xorriso -version
```

should say something like

```
GNU xorriso 1.4.6 : RockRidge filesystem manipulator, libburnia project.
...
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

If so, then you may use the full path to the executable binary as argument to
`grub-mkrescue` option `--xorriso`.

```
grub-mkrescue -o grub.iso --xorriso=/...path.../xorriso-1.4.6/xorriso/xorriso prepared_directory
```

It is supposed that you may move the
executable binary to any other storage location, if this is more convenient
to you.

---

---

While the problem with building GNU xorriso in the Win10-Ubuntu subsystem
was not diagnosed, i added the following instructions about building
a binary on **real Ubuntu** without the Linux kernel dependencies which
probably kept xorriso out of the Win10-Ubuntu repository.

If `xorriso/xorriso` has already been built in the `xorriso-1.4.6` tree,
then first remove all compilation results:

```
make clean
```

Enforce a configuration which does not refer to Linux specific features
and compile:

```
export CFLAGS="-DLibburn_use_sg_dummY"
./configure --disable-libacl --disable-xattr --disable-zlib --disable-libreadline
make
```

The resulting file `xorriso/xorriso` should then be copied into reach of
the Win10-Ubuntu subsystem. Try by `/...path.../xorriso -version` whether
it is willing to start (i.e. whether it finds the necessary libraries).

xorriso builds and runs on Win10-Ubuntu with the
"GNU/Linux SG_IO adapter sg-linux".
But ioctl(SG_IO) or access to optical drives seems not implemented.
No drives get detected.
So it seems better to cause by `-DLibburn_use_sg_dummY` compilation with
"X/Open adapter sg-dummy" which does not depend on Linux specifics and does
not try to operate optical drives at all.

Comment: Thanks. I knew about --xorriso, but I never thought about building it myself. I'm having some build problems: "Makefile:2907: recipe for target 'xorriso/xorrecord.info' failed
make[1]: *** [xorriso/xorrecord.info] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory '/mnt/c/Work/xorriso/xorriso-1.4.6'
Makefile:824: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2" and a warning about makeinfo missing from my system and how it is needed only if I modified a .texi file (which I didn't).

Comment: The .info files are supposed to be up to date in the tar.gz. Let's discuss this by mail and later post the result here. Please send the complete message output of ./configure && make to scdbackup@gmx.net. I will then propose more inquiries or experiments. (This Ubuntu-on-Win-10 stuff seems to be quite new.)

Comment: The reason for the initial build failure has been found. By bad luck, the .texi files were extracted from the tarball one second later than the .info files. So "make" tried to generate .info from .texi but lacked the program "makeinfo" from package "texinfo".